# What does astronomy meta thinks of community wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I can't find that discussion back, but at least stack overflow (the granddady of stack exchanges), I seem to recall community wikis were not an encouraged practice.

Is the astronomy SE against, neutral or pro community wikis?

I think the gist of the opposition against community wiki is that much of the same could be achieved by proposing edits to an existing good answer, but then all the reputations etc. which is an important part of the general workings of an exchange isn't really included anymore.

[The general SE meta post on community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 3):

Community wiki is a valuable tool for answers in some cases, but we do not use it on questions. In some cases the best way to arrive at an answer is by the collaboration of multiple users, that is when community wiki becomes a useful tool--because the post is no longer perceived as being primarily the view of a single author.